# Does every garage represents one school bus or two?

Tags: simcity-2013

When I click on an elementary school building, it shows me that I have two school busses. On the map, however, there is only one, in the covered parking spot. Does that mean that both busses are represented by the one in the shed, or I actually have to build the second shed one to use my second bus? It is unclear from the upgrade screen whether I get another two busses from the purchase of the second shed, or it just shows however many I have already.

As a reference, the police station also states that I have two police cars, and there are actually two cars in the parking lot. But for the fire station, I think I had to buy another garage, unless I am thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes** - each school bus lot will put two school buses on the road.

[image: school bus lot]